# SQLite error opening Symfony app on Heroku

Tags: php, sqlite, symfony, heroku

Error itself:

```
2021-07-20T23:43:33.993462+00:00 app[web.1]: [20-Jul-2021 23:43:33 UTC] [critical] Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\ClassNotFoundError: "Attempted to load class "SQLite3Cache" from namespace "Doctrine\Common\Cache".
2021-07-20T23:43:33.993688+00:00 app[web.1]: Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?" at /app/src/Utils/FilesCache.php line 23
```

The file contents of "FilesCache.php" are similar to what's provided in Symfony's documentation  [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache/adapters/doctrine_adapter.html) with a few additions.

```
<?php
namespace App\Utils;

use App\Utils\Interfaces\CacheInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\FilesystemAdapter;
use Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\TagAwareAdapter;
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\CacheProvider;
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\SQLite3Cache;
use Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\DoctrineAdapter;


class FilesCache implements CacheInterface
{
    public $cache;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //this is error line 23
        $provider = new SQLite3Cache(new \SQLite3(__DIR__ . '/cache/data.db'), 'TableName');

        $this->cache =  new TagAwareAdapter(
            new DoctrineAdapter(
                $provider,
                $namespace = '',
                $defaultLifetime = 0
            )
        );
    }
}
```

I've added both "pdo_sqlite" and "sqlite3" extensions to "composer.json".
Composer update runs without issue.

I'm committing both the "composer.json" and "composer.lock" before pushing the local project repo to Heroku, which runs without issue as well and shows that both extensions are added.

```
remote: -----> Installing platform packages...
remote:        - php (8.0.8)
remote:        - ext-intl (bundled with php)
remote:        - ext-pdo_sqlite (bundled with php)
remote:        - ext-sqlite3 (bundled with php)
remote:        - composer (2.1.3)
remote:        - apache (2.4.48)
remote:        - nginx (1.20.1)
```

I know that SQLite isn't the proper choice for a production database, I'm following a course and I'd like to continue using what's provided from it.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you check which version of doctrine/cache you are using? My guess is, that it's one of the newer releases, which does no longer contain actual cache implementations because the library is being deprecated. Try using the [PDO/DBAL-Adapter instead](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache/adapters/pdo_doctrine_dbal_adapter.html)

Comment: For reference: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-cache/en/2.0/index.html "Please note that doctrine/cache is deprecated and no longer maintained. The last version to include cache drivers is 1.11. The 2.x major release series only provides the interfaces for libraries that need to maintain backward compatibility."

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? This doesn't look related to Heroku to me after all, as that class is part of `doctrine/cache` and not provided by any PHP extension

Comment: @dbrumann It was indeed related to doctrine/cache, I was using a >2.0 version. Thanks for the reference and suggestion, I've changed to a [PDO/DBal Adapter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache/adapters/pdo_doctrine_dbal_adapter.html) and will edit my post with the solution.

Comment: @NicoHaase I realize the title of my question might be slightly incorrect and induce misinterpretation, sorry about that. I was using a different adapter while testing locally, this was a change I had to make to deploy on Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem was the deprecation of doctrine/cache. I switched to a PDOAdapter and this fixed the issue.

```
 <?php
        namespace App\Utils;
        
        use App\Utils\Interfaces\CacheInterface;
        use Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\TagAwareAdapter;
        use Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\PdoAdapter;
        use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Connection;
        
        
        class FilesCache implements CacheInterface
        {
            public $cache;
    
            public function __construct()
            {
                $connection = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection([
                    'url' => 'sqlite:////%kernel.project_dir%/var/cache/data.db'
                ]);
        
                $this->cache =  new TagAwareAdapter(
                    new PdoAdapter(
                        $connection,
                        $namespace = '',
                        $defaultLifetime = 0
                    )
                );
            }
        }
```